# Mule 4 - Convert Array of strings to single string

Tags: arrays, sql-update, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have an array of primary keys that i need for a SQL update statement. My goal here is to NOT loop through each primary key and execute an update statement many times. What i want to do is create a string and only execute the statement 1 time.

Here is my array of primary keys

```
["1234-114600000034-000093-ABCDE","1234-034-114600000378-FGH","1234- 
 114600000034-1146000-JKLMN","1234-1146034-00380-OPQRS","1234- 
 114600000034-1181-TUVWX"]
```

My desired output would be a string like this

```
('1234-114600000034-000093-ABCDE','1234-034-114600000378-FGH','1234- 
 114600000034-1146000-JKLMN','1234-1146034-00380-OPQRS','1234- 
 114600000034-1181-TUVWX')
```

My SQL statement would look something like this

```
UPDATE [TABLE_NAME] SET [COLUMN_NAME] = 1 WHERE ID IN ('1234-114600000034-000093-ABCDE','1234-034-114600000378-FGH','1234- 
 114600000034-1146000-JKLMN','1234-1146034-00380-OPQRS','1234- 
 114600000034-1181-TUVWX')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the ways to do so could be using reduce.

**Script**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
var inp = ["1234-114600000034-000093-ABCDE","1234-034-114600000378-FGH","1234-114600000034-1146000-JKLMN","1234-1146034-00380-OPQRS","1234-114600000034-1181-TUVWX"]
---
('(' ++ (inp reduce ((item, acc = '') -> acc ++ "'" ++ item ++ "',"  )) ++ ')') replace ',)' with ')'
```

**Output**

```
('1234-114600000034-000093-ABCDE','1234-034-114600000378-FGH','1234-114600000034-1146000-JKLMN','1234-1146034-00380-OPQRS','1234-114600000034-1181-TUVWX')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Nice solution. I upvoted but due to my reputation being so low it isnt showing up. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `joinBy` function and then prepend and append the quote and parenthesis.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var ids = ["1234-114600000034-000093-ABCDE","1234-034-114600000378-FGH",
    "1234-114600000034-1146000-JKLMN","1234-1146034-00380-OPQRS",
    "1234-114600000034-1181-TUVWX"]
---
"UPDATE [TABLE_NAME] SET [COLUMN_NAME] = 1 WHERE ID IN ('" 
    ++  (ids joinBy  "','") ++ "')"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to get desired Output

in the below code, I am taking an array of primary keys as a variable and performing the logic on it

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java

var inputPayload = ["1234-114600000034-000093-ABCDE","1234-034-114600000378-FGH","1234-114600000034-1146000-JKLMN","1234-1146034-00380-OPQRS","1234- 114600000034-1181-TUVWX"]

---
"UPDATE [TABLE_NAME] SET [COLUMN_NAME] = 1 WHERE ID IN " ++ ((write(inputPayload, "application/json")) replace "[" with "(") replace "]" with ")"
```

The output of above logic would be

```
UPDATE [TABLE_NAME) SET [COLUMN_NAME) = 1 WHERE ID IN (
  "1234-114600000034-000093-ABCDE",
  "1234-034-114600000378-FGH",
  "1234-114600000034-1146000-JKLMN",
  "1234-1146034-00380-OPQRS",
  "1234- 114600000034-1181-TUVWX"
)
```